# Running two Django projects on one droplet with Gunicorn and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I've exhausted myself trying to solve this, I hope I can get some help

I wish to host two Django projects on a single DigitalOcean droplet. 
I can host one site with no problem after following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04#checking-for-the-gunicorn-socket-file) but I just cant figure out a way to make this work with two sites. 
Currently example.com works, and example2.com has the problem that it is Using project1 settings module - project1.settings. I need it to use project2.settings module from it's project directory and I've no idea how to do this.

My gunicorn.socket file for project1:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

My gunicorn.socket file for project2:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/project2.gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

My gunicorn.service file for project1:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=rain
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/rain/rv/project1-web
ExecStart=/home/rain/rv/rv-env/bin/gunicorn \
      --access-logfile - \
      --workers 3 \
      --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
      project1.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I figured there should be a second service file for the other project so I created project2.gunicorn.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=project2.gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=rain
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/rain/rv/project2-web
ExecStart=/home/rain/rv/rv-env/bin/gunicorn \
      --access-logfile - \
      --workers 3 \
      --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
      project2.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My nginx sites-available file for project1:

```
server {
    server_name example.com; 
    charset     utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/rain/rv/project1-web;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot    
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen      80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And another server block for project2:

```
server {
    server_name example2.com; 
    charset     utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/rain/rv/project2-web;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/project2.gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot    
}

server {
    server_name www.example2.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    return 301 https://example2.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    if ($host = www.example2.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example2.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen      80;
    server_name example2.com www.example2.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: You need separate sockets.

Comment: Made another socket 'project2.gunicorn.socket' and now the situation with the settings module is reversed. Can i run two sockets simultaneously?

Comment: That wasn't what I meant. (I don't know what that "gunicorn.socket" file is supposed to do at all, you don't need it.) But the --bind parameter for your gunicorn invocations - and the matching proxy_pass parameter for nginx - needs to be different for each site.

Comment: Ok, Great! Thank you A lot it works now. Both of the sites are running, but now I have to solve the redirection issue. www.example.com and www.example2.com do not redirect properly to example.com and example2.com respectively.